# È corretto dire "aumentare di più"?

Tags: word-usage

Siccome "aumentare" significa "rendere maggiore, accrescere, salire a valori più alti", non sono sicura che "aumentare di più" sia un'espressione corretta. Per esempio, questa frase sarebbe corretta?

> Il governo ha aumentato l'età della pensione e, probabilmente, l'aumenterà ancora di più.

Comment: Magari implica un'accelerazione dell'oggetto in questione, ovvero che non solo lo aumento ma che aumento la velocità con cui lo aumento.

Comment: @martina: Ma, per indicare un'accelerazione, non si dovrebbe dire "aumentare più"?

Comment: Interessante questione: questo è il caso in cui è necessario usare anche la preposizione 'di'. Credo che dipenda dal tipo di verbo: sono i costrutti del tipo *andare più veloce, dormire più a lungo* che non la vogliono, vale a dire quei costrutti dove l'aggettivo o avverbio è specificato.

Comment: @martina: Dunque, si dovrebbe dire: "I prezzi hanno aumentato di più in febbraio che in gennaio"?

Comment: @Charo "I prezzi sono aumentati di più a Febbraio che a Gennaio"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sì. "Di più" significa sia "maggiormente" che "ulteriormente", il primo caso è il caso di:
"Lavora di più!" o "Dormire di più aiuta la salute". Il secondo caso è quello che hai citato. 
La differenza è sottile: si usa maggiormente quando si parla di quantità generiche. Si usa ulteriormente quando si parla di quantità che hanno una soglia che può venire oltrepassata. Sono a volte intercambiabili. (Maggiori profitti è uguale ad ulteriori profitti, la sfumatura di significato è impercettibile).

Comment: Io suggerirei anche "[...] continerà a farlo."

Comment: "continuare a farlo" o "farlo ulteriormente" non hanno differenze significative.