# Sull'uso delle maiuscole e le preposizioni con i nomi dei mesi

Tags: grammar, prepositions, orthography, capitalization

In un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5146/%C3%88-corretto-dire-aumentare-di-pi%C3%B9), il mio tentativo di frase

> I prezzi hanno aumentato di più in febbraio che in gennaio

è stato corretto in questo modo

> I prezzi sono aumentati di più a Febbraio che a Gennaio.

L'uso dell'ausiliare "essere" è chiaro perché in questa frase si sta facendo un uso intransitivo del verbo "aumentare". Quello che non è chiaro a me è l'uso delle maiuscole e della preposizione "a" con i nomi dei mesi.

Nel libro *Grammatica italiana per stranieri* di Maria Cristina Peccianti (Giunti Editori, 2013) ho letto questa spiegazione in riferimento all'uso delle preposizioni con i nomi dei mesi:

> «Con **i mesi** si può usare la preposizione *di*, o la preposizione *a*, o la preposizione *in*, tutte semplici:
>
> - ***Di*** giugno ci saranno gli esami.
> - ***A*** giugno ci saranno gli esami.
> - ***In*** giugno ci saranno gli esami.»

Ho notato che, negli esempi di questo libro, il mese "giugno" viene scritto con la minuscola. Le mie domande sono: è corretto scrivere i nomi dei mesi con la maiuscola? Nella frase che si riferisce ai prezzi, è preferibile per qualche ragione usare la preposizione "a" e non la preposizione "in"? Perché?

Comment: I nomi dei mesi seguono l'andamento della frase. Se la cominciano devono essere scritti in maiuscolo, diversamente in minuscolo. Quindi a mio avviso la correzione della tua frase è errata (relativamente alla maiuscola sul nome del mese). http://www.treccani.it/magazine/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_362.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"A" e "in" secondo me vanno entrambe bene coi mesi, con piccole variazioni regionali (direi che al nord si usa più "in", e al sud "a").

"Di", invece, non l'ho mai visto né sentito e mi suona sbagliato se usato nel senso di cui sopra. Naturalmente possiamo dire

> Quest'esercizio sarà nell'esame di giugno

ma stiamo già cambiando il senso.

**Edit**: ok, forse capisco a cosa si riferisce il "di" È un uso piuttosto ristretto, e io l'ho sempre sentito con i giorni della settimana, mai coi mesi (anche se ammetto che in via teorica potrebbe forse applicarsi ai mesi, ma non ne sono sicuro):

> Gli esami [saranno|si terranno] **di** lunedì

che significa: ogni volta che si svolgerà qualche esame, sarà un lunedì (ad esempio, perché gli esami si svolgono tutti i lunedì, o perché vengono programmati sempre in modo che cadano in un lunedì, etc.). Una formulazione alternativa è:

> Gli esami [saranno|si terranno] **al** lunedì

Quindi se lo usiamo per i mesi *potrebbe* saltare fuori qualcosa del genere:

> Gli esami saranno di giugno

ma, come dicevo, suona stranissimo e io personalmente non l'ho mai sentito; la forma corrente è

> Gli esami saranno **in|a** giugno

Sulla questione maiuscolo/minuscolo, generalmente i giorni della settimana e i mesi si scrivono in minuscolo, su questo sembra esserci abbastanza accordo (vedi ad esempio [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-delle-maiuscole_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/), [Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/alcuni-quesiti-nomi-mesi-giorni-settimana), puoi trovare ulteriori conferme con google). Poi, naturalmente, non c'è una regola che vieti di scriverli in maiuscolo, in fin dei conti sono pur sempre nomi propri, pertanto suppongo che sia ancora possibile incontrarli in maiuscolo. Però direi che è un uso molto minoritario o addirittura ormai scomparso (come d'altronde anche altri usi delle maiuscole, suppongo influiscano anche ragioni di comodità e praticità).

Comment: Sospetto che chi scrive i nomi dei mesi maiuscoli si lasci influenzare dall'uso inglese.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG io sono uno di quelli...

Comment: Dici che non c'è una regola, ma per Treccani c'è: «I nomi dei giorni della settimana e dei mesi vanno scritti con l’iniziale minuscola»

Comment: Sì, però per esempio la Crusca dice: "I nomi dei giorni della settimana e dei mesi dell'anno non richiedono la maiuscola, eccetto <casi non rilevanti qui>..." che è già più ambiguo.